# Postgres - Is there a faster way to update a table with information from another DB?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm updating a table called `Recipes` and setting the `ImageUrl` column to a matching row in a VIEW.  My UPDATE statement is:

```
UPDATE Recipes R
  SET ImageUrl=L.ImageUrl
  FROM Link.Recipes L
  WHERE L.RecipeId=R.RecipeId AND L.ImageUrl is not null;
```

`Link.Recipes` is a VIEW that returns all `Recipes` rows from another database on a different server, so it's already pretty slow:

> Query returned successfully: 8541 rows affected, 173236 ms execution
>   time.

I'd like to see if there's a way to make it a bit faster.  INSERT statements involving the same view with a similar number of rows are *much* faster, so there's something different going on here.

There is of course an index on `RecipeId`, however `ImageUrl` has no indexes in either table.  Is there a better way I can write this UPDATE statement that won't take nearly 3 minutes?

**Explain:**

```
'Update  (cost=0.00..4136.54 rows=995 width=1531)'
'  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..4136.54 rows=995 width=1531)'
'        ->  Function Scan on dblink t1  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=995 width=266)'
'              Filter: (imageurl IS NOT NULL)'
'        ->  Index Scan using recipes_pkey on recipes r  (cost=0.00..4.13 rows=1 width=1281)'
'              Index Cond: (r.recipeid = t1.recipeid)'
```

**Explain Analyze:**

```
'Update  (cost=0.00..4233.18 rows=995 width=1532) (actual time=168887.016..168887.016 rows=0 loops=1)'
'  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..4233.18 rows=995 width=1532) (actual time=23689.440..24500.006 rows=8549 loops=1)'
'        ->  Function Scan on dblink t1  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=995 width=266) (actual time=23689.250..23749.288 rows=8550 loops=1)'
'              Filter: (imageurl IS NOT NULL)'
'        ->  Index Scan using recipes_pkey on recipes r  (cost=0.00..4.23 rows=1 width=1282) (actual time=0.083..0.085 rows=1 loops=8550)'
'              Index Cond: (r.recipeid = t1.recipeid)'
'Trigger trg_recipes_searchupdate: time=3808.617 calls=8549'
'Total runtime: 168889.272 ms'
```

Comment: The view is using dblink, that is much slower because of the extra database connection. Could you also show us the result from EXPLAIN ANALYZE? That shows you where the time is spend.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - Agreed.  However, I'm wondering why it's considerably slower than just a `INSERT INTO Recipes SELECT * FROM Link.Recipes;`

Comment: @FrankHeikens - Added the Explain Analyze

Comment: What's the trigger doing? It's used 8549 times and slow. dblink is the other bottleneck, do you really need it?

Comment: @FrankHeikens - The trigger is updating a *tsvector* column, used in full text search.  I definitely don't need to run it on every row, I could just update all the rows at the end.  Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be worth creating a partial index on imageurl not null.  Read more about that here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html

Comment: Also, how many rows are in Recipe?  What does the explain plan look like?

Comment: I can give it another shot with the partial index on the remote table.    I also added the explain.  Both Recipes tables have about 10,000 rows.

Comment: I'm curious if the index would even help.  The VIEW just calls into the DBLink function which does a `SELECT *` from the remote table.  Since the VIEW is not indexed, an index on the remote table would probably not even get used, right?

Comment: No, I wouldn't expect it to get used in that case.  It might be worth creating a different view that filters imageurl remotely?

Comment: Yea, that would probably do it, however I wanted to make this query flexible enough to update any column or columns.  I actually just removed the WHERE clause and it's only slightly faster.  I think most of the time spent is just sending data across the network.

Comment: I've usually found that it's a better plan to pull the entire result set to the local database before trying an update like this.  This is true even with Oracle and the driving_site hint.  I wouldn't really expect it to take long to CTAS a 10k row table.